# Installing Solr on Server: Location?

Tags: java, drupal, solr, tomcat6

Ok, I've been following [this tutorial](http://www.lullabot.com/blog/article/installing-solr-use-drupal) on getting Solr installed on a server and accessible through Drupal. My question is my placement of Solr in the correct spot?

I know my Java works, testing with `java -version`
I know my Tomcat works, tested with `service tomcat6 start: Starting tomcat6 [ OK ]`

*Note:* Although I can't access Tomcat via http:website.com:8080 (I left the port default)

My current setup follows:

```
/usr/bin/java                           (Java installation - via yum)
/usr/share/tomcat6                      (Tomcat installation - via yum)

/opt/solr                               (Solr Instance Installation - manually)

/opt/share/tomcat6/solr/drupal-solr     (One Solr Core - manually)

/home/website1/public_html              (just a site - I'd like to use Solr here)
/home/website2/public_html              (just another site)
/home/website3/public_html              (just another site)
```

As stated, "Solr is capable of providing **multiple search indexes**, or **cores**, using just one instance of the Solr application. Each core is independently configured, and there is a single configuration file to define each of the cores."

So say if my website1 needs access to one of my **cores** of Solr. Would this core need to be installed at...

```
/home/website1/                         (where my Solr Core should be?)
/home/website1/public_html              (my website files - drupal install)
```

...correct? 
...or can I leave my Solr and everything else installed in root **above** all my websites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may debug Tomcat by

1. Do a `curl localhost:8080` if you see Tomcat response, then may be outbound traffic from port 8080 is blocked in security groups or IPTABLES of your webserver
2. If in step1, curl fails, then Tomcat is not running on 8080, it is on some other port. Please refer to this to find correct port: `http://askubuntu.com/questions/143785/what-port-is-tomcat-6-running-on`

Yes, you can install Solr anywhere. You have to let tomcat know where Solr is installed, which is the **Step 5: Create the Solr context file** in the documentation you have referred to.

Suppose your Solr is at:

/solr

Suppose your multi-cores names are site1, site2, site3, then the multicore structure will look like:

> /solr
>
> /solr/site1
>
> /solr/site2
>
> /solr/site3

Yes, each core will have its own conf directory, with its unique config files such as solrconfig.xml, schema.xml, synonyms.txt etc...

Now if your tomcat is running on port 8080, and suppose your IP is 10.20.30.40, you will be able to access listing of all cores at: 10.20.30.40:8080/solr/

Comment: Now when I do `curl localhost:8080` I do see the source to a webpage for Tomcat6. Although when I use `<mysiteip>:8080` I can't get anything to appear. Why is this? Thanks again for the reply.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little? Do you have a DNS associated with your site? Are you curling on your site IP:8080 from the webserver or are you trying to load it in a browser? May be you need to modify security groups or IPTABLES to allow outbound traffic on port 8080

Comment: Running the `curl` while `SSH`'ed into the server. That seems to work and pulls up the source code to a tomcat webpage. But if I try to do `<server-ip>:8080` in a web browser, it won't work. I am unsure of the current security groups or IPTABLES. I will Google this here later and look into it.

Comment: Found the issue, I did not have a port open for 8080. I turned off `iptables` and <ip>:8080 in my browser worked like a charm. So I'll look further into this issue. Thanks a ton for the direction and answering my question over the proper structure for Solr cores.